# Aligning Town/Range with section lines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, plss

Is there a tool in ArcGIS Desktop that will allow me to snap or align a township/range layer to the section layer?

The layers that I have don't quite line up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArcGIS [Snap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000) tool will do this for you (standard and up license level).

You need to fill in what type of snapping you are looking for in the Type column. Also the Distance of the snapping. Also keep in mind this is a tool with no outputs, so **make copies of your input data before trying.**